# How to generate a CSV file with accented characters using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

[Accented characters](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/accents) like *enie* (ñ) are difficult to handle when generating CSV files. The tendency is one might end up having different and unexpected characters.

In my case, the CSV file I generated got a `\1\1` instead of `ñ`. Thus instead of having `Niño` it got `Ni\1\1o`.

Is this even possible to fix? How to generate a CSV file with accented characters using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the data check

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php
```

Comment: I did try `$drum_roll = mb_convert_encoding( $accented_string, 'ISO-8859-1');` but it did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customers_Export.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```